# How to read pixels in four corners of a BitmapSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapsource

I have a .NET [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) object. I would like to read the four pixels in corners of the bitmap, and test whether all of them are darker than white. How can I do that?

Edit: I wouldn't mind converting this object to another type with a better API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BitmapSource has a [CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616042.aspx) method that can be used to get one or more pixel values.

A helper method that gets a single pixel value at a given pixel coordinate may look like shown below. Note that it perhaps has to be extended to support all required pixel formats.

```
public static Color GetPixelColor(BitmapSource bitmap, int x, int y)
{
    Color color;
    var bytesPerPixel = (bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    var bytes = new byte[bytesPerPixel];
    var rect = new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1);

    bitmap.CopyPixels(rect, bytes, bytesPerPixel, 0);

    if (bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Bgra32)
    {
        color = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
    }
    else if (bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Bgr32)
    {
        color = Color.FromRgb(bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
    }
    // handle other required formats
    else
    {
        color = Colors.Black;
    }

    return color;
}
```

You would use the method like this:

```
var topLeftColor = GetPixelColor(bitmap, 0, 0);
var topRightColor = GetPixelColor(bitmap, bitmap.PixelWidth - 1, 0);
var bottomLeftColor = GetPixelColor(bitmap, 0, bitmap.PixelHeight - 1);
var bottomRightColor = GetPixelColor(bitmap, bitmap.PixelWidth - 1, bitmap.PixelHeight - 1);
```

Comment: You can just convert bmp to required format:
            if (bitmap.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32)
                bitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bitmap, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);